# CefSharp.Wpf: Open csv, mailto and pdf with Process.Start(...)

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I need to handle different content types from f:///.  My application renders offline websites in a WPF application.  Everything is working except for links to other content files (csv, mailto and pdf).

- If I register a `CefCustomScheme` for "mailto", then I get the ProcessRequestAsync and can run the Process.Start(...).  **However another blank window also popup.**
- If I then add a second `CefCustomScheme` for "file", then nothing happens.  None of the `ISchemeHandler` ProcessRequestAsync methods are invoked.

I must be able to handle all requests, excluding *.html, in a separate handler

Essentially I just want to replicate the behavior of the MS Web-browser Control.  There all I did was point to the entry page (index.htm), and everything loaded.  Then if a user clicks any link, the control handled the action and started the correct process (content handler, i.e. Excel for Csv).

The code:

```
// Startup
  var settings = new CefSettings();
  settings.LogFile = @"c:\temp\ceflog.txt";
  settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Verbose;
  settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
  CefCustomScheme mailtoScheme = new CefCustomScheme();
  mailtoScheme.SchemeName = "mailto";
  mailtoScheme.SchemeHandlerFactory = new SchemeHandlerFactory();

  CefCustomScheme filesScheme = new CefCustomScheme();
  mailtoScheme.SchemeName = "file";
  mailtoScheme.SchemeHandlerFactory = new SchemeHandlerFactory();

  settings.RegisterScheme(mailtoScheme);
  settings.RegisterScheme(filesScheme);

  if (!Cef.Initialize(settings))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to initialize the browser factory");
```

-- SchemeHandlerFactory

```
public class SchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory  {
public ISchemeHandler Create()    {
  return new CustomSchemeHandler();
}
```

}

-- Handler

```
public class CustomSchemeHandler : ISchemeHandler  {
private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
public bool ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ISchemeHandlerResponse response, OnRequestCompletedHandler requestCompletedCallback)    {
  _log.DebugFormat("Processing url: {0}", request.Dump());

  var knownContentTypes = new[] {".csv", ".xsls", ".xlsx", ".pdf", ".txt"};
  var ext=Path.GetExtension(request.Url);
  if(knownContentTypes.Contains(ext))      {
    _log.DebugFormat("Starting process for: {0}",request.Url);
    Process.Start(request.Url);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the `ISchemeHandler`s and how you register them?

Comment: Hi @SzabolcsDézsi, I updated the question and added as much detail as possbile

Comment: When you create the `filesScheme`, you still refer to the `mailtoScheme` after that.

I wasn't able to make the file links work with the scheme handler approach.

If you set the `RequestHandler` of your browser control, and put the code where you start the process into the `OnBeforeBrowse` method you can achieve the effect you'd like.

I tried it with CefSharp.Wpf 37.0.0

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to implement an IRequestHandler and use the OnBeforeResourceLoad event to check what content was requested.  The ISchemeHandler is used for the "mailto" actions.

In my case I had to assign the request handler after the frame loaded.  This allowed the web browser to render all content first.

Code sample [GitHub example](https://github.com/jacodv/CefSharp.MinimalExample/)